# Cannot pass string from managed c# to unmanaged c

Tags: c#, c, marshalling, dllimport

I've already tried multiple methods shown in this site to pass string from c# to c, but the function in the C code keeps getting null arguments instead.

This is my C function:

```
__declspec(dllexport) BOOL __cdecl GetSignatureInfo(char* fileName, char* output)
```

and my c# usage:

```
[DllImport("GetSignature.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int GetSignatureInfo([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string filePath, StringBuilder output);
```

Am I doing anything wrong here?
Thanks in advance.

Edit: This is how I call the function:

```
 StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(256);
    string spath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";
    Console.WriteLine(Detect.GetSignatureInfo(spath, output));
```

Comment: How are you calling it?

Comment: How do you initialize `output`? Please add the relevant code to the question.

Comment: Hmm, that does look reasonable enough. Is the dll 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: Umm, the configuration says "Mixed Platforms"

Comment: Hmm, try forcing both projects to 32 bit and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: It seems that the string was passed correctly, but the C program uses a different format of strings... It performs 'lstrcpynW' on the string then passes it to an outside function.

Comment: Ah ok. Tried `UnmanagedType.LPWStr`?

Comment: Replaced the command to mbstowcs, works now :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was incorrect format of strings. Switched the `lstrcpynW` to `mbstowcs` and it works now.